# File Creation, Management and Removal in C++ using xCode

Tags: c++, xcode

I am a fairly novice programmer, taking a few courses in my second year of highschool, and I have ran into a few problems. So let's get on with it.

Long story short, I have learnt how to create files like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string Test;
    ofstream file;
    file.open("Cookies.txt");
    if(file.is_open()){
        file << "I have cookies! :3" << endl;
        file.close();
    }
    else{
        cout << "Error. No file has been created." << endl;
    }
    ifstream cookies;
    cookies.open("Cookies.txt");
    if(cookies.is_open()){
        cout << cookies.rdbuf();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But my question now is, how do I like "use" what is in this file? Like if I want to save variables, or import the "I have cookies! :3" to a string variable in the main program. Because it seems reasonable that it should be possible, I have just not found out how to yet.

Also, how do I delete files that I have created? Because something like
file.delete("Cookies.txt"); does not work at all.

Thank you for your answers in advance.
Best regards, Staggen.

Comment: Probably you should follow a complete tutorial on file IO etc. This question is really broad, and your specific questions should be covered there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read from a file in a similar manner to writing to it, using an `ifstream` (input filestream) instead of an `ofstream` (output filestream), and using the `>>` operator to read into variables. It does default to reading a single value at a time, and for strings that translates into "words":

So:

```
if (cookies.is_open())
{
  std::string word;

  while (cookies >> word) // read from the filestream into "line"
  {
    std::cout << "Read a word: " << line << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This is a fairly good method for reading different data types.

To read the entire line, you can use [std::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) with the newline character as the delimiter:

```
if (cookies.is_open())
{
  std::string line;

  while (std::getline(cookies, line, '\n'))
  {
    std::cout << "Read a line: " << line << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Deleting a file is an OS-level activity unrelated to reading/writing to files. The `<cstdio>` header includes [std::remove()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/) which will delete files.

@anderas is right; you should go through [a tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) on file I/O in order to learn or solidify the basics.